# javascript push not working in array inside object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, google-apps-script, prototype

As you can see in the code, i tried to dynamically create arrays inside an object, it doesn't have a problem when debugging, but when i tried to use push method in the array it throws an error. By the way this is in google app script.

**Push function not found in the object [object Object]: TypeError. (line 32, file**

```
var LoopQuestGuildAchievementReward = function (spread_sheet, master_name, is_update) {
  initializeBase(this, MasterBase, [spread_sheet, master_name, is_update]);

  this.guild_achievement_columns = new Object();
  this.create_guild_achievement_columns = function () {
    var guild_achievement_coloumn_names = ['ids', 'event_ids', 'range_starts', 'range_ends', 'incentive_ids'];

    for (var i = 0; i < guild_achievement_coloumn_names.length; i++) {
      if (!this.guild_achievement_columns[guild_achievement_coloumn_names[i]]) {
        this.guild_achievement_columns[guild_achievement_coloumn_names[i]] = {};
      };
    };
  };
};

LoopQuestGuildAchievementReward.prototype.setMaster = function(option) {
  if (!option || !option.summary_values || !option.batch_reward_values) {
    throw "Argument exception.";
  };

  var event_id = option.summary_values[8][0];
  var incentive_values = option.batch_reward_values;
  var incentive_master_id = Commons.getIncentiveId(1, event_id, 5);
  var data_row_number = searchRowNumberWrittenLavelInColumn_(incentive_values, 1, "reach num") + 1;
  var guild_achievement_last_id = Commons.getLatestId("loop_quest_guild_achievement_reward", "ja") + 1;

  this.create_guild_achievement_columns();

  while (data_row_number < incentive_values.length && incentive_values[data_row_number][1] != "") {
    var reach_number = incentive_values[data_row_number][1];
    Logger.log(this.guild_achievement_columns.ids);
    this.guild_achievement_columns.ids.push(guild_achievement_last_id); // <- this where the error message points (line no. 32)
    // this.guild_achievement_columns.event_ids.push(event_id);
    // this.guild_achievement_columns.range_starts.push(reach_number);
    // this.guild_achievement_columns.range_ends.push(reach_number - 1);
    // this.guild_achievement_columns.incentive_ids.push(incentive_master_id);

    guild_achievement_last_id++;
    incentive_master_id++;
    data_row_number++;
  }

  Logger.log(this.guild_achievement_columns);
};
```

Comment: your "ids" is a object not a array.objects do not have push method.in your for loop ,you create object for "ids".see this line this.guild_achievement_columns[guild_achievement_coloumn_names[i]] = {}

Comment: ah yes, thanks it should be [] not {}

Answer (score 0):

After asking my superior he mention that curly braces refer to objects and brackets refer to array.

Object: this.guild_achievement_columns[guild_achievement_coloumn_names[i]] = {};

Array: this.guild_achievement_columns[guild_achievement_coloumn_names[i]] = [];